# What is the name of a vector with all equal elements?

Tags: vectors

Is there a name for a vector with all equal elements? If so, what is it?

For example,

$$ (7, 7, 7, 7, 7) $$

Comment: I've never heard of a name for that.  But if it were up to me I'd call it a "pure diagonal" vector.

Comment: "Pure diagonal" works for me.

Comment: I did a bit of googling and I can't seem to find a name for such an object anywhere.  So seems you're free to use "pure diagonal" but just make sure to define that term explicitly where you use it, since it is non-standard.

Comment: The first words that came to my mind were "main diagonal" (analogous to the main diagonal of a cube). I would still be careful to define it before using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [relevant](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9898/notation-for-the-all-ones-vector). Given how much of a hullabaloo there is over just the all-ones vector, I'm guessing there is no standard name for the more general vectors with all equal elements.

If we use $\vec{1}$ for the all-ones vector, in $\mathbb{R}^5$ we could write

$$(7,7,7,7,7) = 7 \cdot \vec{1}$$

Comment: I'll probably go with "pure diagonal" (as I need a name in the code I'm writing), but this seems like the most accurate answer. I guess all-sevens would also work. :)

Answer (score 2):

*Diagonal vector* which makes equal angle to co-ordinates axes.